# SQLite Ionic Plugin Error

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sqlite

I'm creating a database test in my Ionic application, based on the original documentation from [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/) , but when I create and run the app, appear this following error on terminal:

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined**
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

I installed ng-cordova plugin and added ng-cordova.min.js in index.html.

Comment: you check to http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/integrate-sqlite-plugin-in-phonegap-for.html  may be its helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running in a browser, the cordova.js and the expected device features are not available.

These are typically gotten around with 'mocks,' stubs of code that overload certain functions. ngCordova provides some. To use them, add the ngCordova.mocks.js file to your karma.conf.

That said, the mocks are not guaranteed to fully test all of the ngCordova functionality and you might need to emulate. [From the docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/).

> Only develop on your phone
>
> Cordova plugins do not work while developing in your browser, because
>   each plugin accesses a specific API (such as camera, microphone,
>   accelerometer) which is not available in your browser. Additionally,
>   some plugins don’t work in the emulator, such as the Camera plugin, so
>   development on your physical device is required.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins won't work on browser and emulator. You need to test your app with real device. especially when you are dealing with database. Since the plugins do not work everything you try to access from plugin will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the problem by removing the `cordova-sqlite-plugin` plugin and adding `cordova-sqlite-storage`.

Then I typed ionic state reset to reinstall the plugins I defined on package.json

And it worked well

=> This is in the case of a mobile device, for browser, it is necessary to use:

```
$window.openDatabase("databasename" , '', 'database', 2000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/):

When you see this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined

It is happening for one of a few reasons:

You are not wrapping the `$cordovaSQLite` methods in the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` function.
You are trying to test this native plugin from a web browser.
You have not actually installed the base SQLite plugin into your project.
The most common reasons for this error are #1 and #2. Native plugins must be used only after the application is confirmed ready, thus the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` method. Since native plugins use native code, you cannot test them from your web browser.

Read through the tutorial I linked because it should help you.